# Append multiple CSVs ignoring repeated headers

Tags: linux, csv, unix, append

I have many CSVs with the same fields and same name (`"data.csv"`). Each csv has a header and multiple lines and is inside a different folder.

E.g. `folder1` has a csv called `data.csv`:

```
NAME, COUNTRY  
JOHN, USA
MARY, Panama
```

`folder2` has a csv called `data.csv`:

```
NAME, COUNTRY  
James, UK
Jim, India
```

`folder3` has a csv called `data.csv`:

```
NAME, COUNTRY  
James, UK
Jim, India
```

Now I want to combine all csv's into one, but without repeating the headers.

So far I am doing:

```
 find . -name "data.csv" | xargs cat > mergedCSV
```

Which works fine, except for the repeated headers.

Comment: Where are the commas in your example CSV files?

Comment: They are between name and country. Sorry. I will edit.

Comment: You should not have a comma and a space to separate columns, comma will just do fine (or maybe it was a <tab>?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csvstack` from the handy [csvkit package](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to concatenate multiple CSV files with the same layout:

```bash
find . -name data.csv | xargs csvstack > mergedCSV
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use miller very easily with the "cat" built-in command/[verb](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/index.html#cat)

```
find . -name data.csv | xargs mlr --csv cat
```

and if you want pretty formatting with 3 files as input:

```
mlr --opprint --barred --icsv cat a/data.csv b/data.csv c/data.csv
+-------+------------+
| NAME  |  COUNTRY   |
+-------+------------+
| JOHN  |  USA       |
| MARY  |  Panama    |
| James |  UK        |
| Jim   |  India     |
| James |  UK        |
| Jim   |  India     |
+-------+------------+
```

If you want to go much further in CSV/TSV/JSON parsing, Miller is the tool of choice to avoid using several Unix commands such as sed, awk, sort, cut join... and with a much better handling of separators and escaping.